# Javascript-event listener not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, contact-form-7

Is there any workaround for this bug in IE11. The code provided works fine for other browsers and Edge so I was hoping to find a workaround/solution here is the code:

```js
document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) {
  var inputs = event.detail.inputs;

  if ('2425' == event.detail.contactFormId) {
    console.log('Test Click');
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

    form_data = {
      username: username,
      password: password
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify(form_data),
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        localStorage.setItem("api_keyF", response.api_key);
        localStorage.setItem("is_trial", response.is_trial);
        for (i = 0; i < response.user_privileges.length; i++) {
          var service_type_id = response.user_privileges[i].service_type_id;
          localStorage.setItem("serviceid" + service_type_id, service_type_id);
        }

        /**alert(response.api_key + ' ' + response.user_privileges{service_type_id});*/

        window.location.href = "login-services/";
      },
      error: function(response) {
        console.log(response.responseJSON.message);
        //                var message = '<div class="alert alert-content-danger row">';
        // toastr.error(response.responseJSON.message);  
        // $('#username').addClass('error-border');
        // $('#password').addClass('error-border');
        // $('.username').text(response.responseJSON.message);                  
        // $('.password').text(response.responseJSON.message);          

        // document.getElementById("displayerror").style.display = "block";
        // document.getElementById("loginban").style.display = "block";                     
        // document.getElementById('displayerror').innerHTML = response.responseJSON.message;

        errorsoftlock = response.responseJSON.message;

        if (errorsoftlock == "Your account is locked. Please wait for 5 minutes.") {
          document.getElementById("displayerror").style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById("loginban").style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById('displayerror').innerHTML = "Oops! Your account has been temporarily locked. Please wait for 5 minutes before trying again.";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("displayerror").style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById("loginban").style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById('displayerror').innerHTML = response.responseJSON.message;
        }
        //                  $('.testerror').html(response.responsetesterrorJSON.message);
        //document.getElementsByClassName("testerror").innerHTML = response.responseJSON.message;
      }
    });
  }
}, false);
```

the expected behavior would be once I click on the button it would make an api call and redirect me to a homepage. this is true for browsers except IE11. In IE11 i am able to click the button but nothing happens. I have also tried using 
attachEvent() reading about possible workarounds but this does not work as well. hoping to find a possible solution for this issue.

Comment: Have you looked at the developer tools in the Console tab to see if you are getting an error?

Comment: @ScottMarcus there were no errors the event does not fire